# Count of the different combination of two attributes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, count, cross-tabulation

I've been trying in vain to use the field calculator in QGIS 2.8 to count the combinations of two attributes in two separate columns.

First column is called `"Alds_klass"` and second is called `"bygn_klass"`. I want to count the different combinations of the two columns, not the sum, but the number of each combination.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you're ready NOT to use the field calculator i would create a **virtual layer** based on the following query (to adapt) :

```
select count(*) as tot, col_a, col_b from my_table
group by col_a, col_b
order by tot desc
```

Which would be "dynamic" ...

(implies to use a newer QGIS version...)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the tool "Statistics by categories" (in the processing toolbox in QGIS 3.2)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column and fill it with a `case when` or `if` clause looping over all possible values. Assign each combination a different letter of the alphabet, and then do a statistical analysis of the new column.

Or just load it into a database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to populate `Count_Al_b` with the total count of combinations `Alds_class+bygn_class` you can use collections.Counter:

> ...where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are
>   stored as dictionary values.

```
print 'start'
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
from collections import Counter

alds = "Alds_klass"
bygn = "bygn_klass"
totcount = "Count_Al_b"
datafile = '/media/bera/my_03.shp' #Change

layer = QgsVectorLayer(datafile, 'temp', 'ogr')
c = Counter([(f[alds],f[bygn]) for f in layer.getFeatures()])

layer.startEditing()
it = layer.getFeatures()
for feat in it:
    layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(),layer.fieldNameIndex(totcount),c[(feat[alds],feat[bygn])])
    #layer.fields().indexFromName(totcount) python 3/QGIS 3
layer.commitChanges()
print 'stop'
```

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use the field calculator to create a virtual field containing the concatenation (i.e. combination) of your two fields, like this:

[image]

The underscore `'_'` ist just for better readabilty and does not affect the result.

Then use the 'Show statistical summary' button (the button with the big *sigma*):

[image]

Herein select your layer and the virtual field you just created, and under **Count (distinct)** you will find the count of your columns combinations:

[image]

The virtual field and the tool do dynamically refresh when data changes.